# Should i still support Internet explorer in 2019?

Tags: internet-explorer, responsive-design

Is there any reason to support Internet Explorer nowadays? I myself have few cons and pros to list about supporting Internet Explorer but i want to hear other developers opinion about developing for Internet Explorer.

### Pros

- More users are able to use webservices
- If it works on IE it works on any other modern browser too

### Cons

- Developers need to use custom hacks and tricks for IE
- Alot of money and time is used to little userbase of older versions of IE

What do you other developers think about this? I think this discussion is relevant because some developers myself included just can't wait Internet Explorer to finally sink and let us use more modern technologies.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your target audience though. Many corporations still strictly use IE. Including the corp I work for with about 100K employees and a very standardised desktop environment. Some power users in the company can use Chrome, but 99% of the employees are stuck with IE.

There are thousands of intranet pages originally designed with IE in mind, so heavy handed browser upgrades are not an option for many corps like these.

If you target mostly mobile users with Android/IOS, or home users, IE usage becomes negligible and I personally don't develop for IE in such cases. Not worth the countless hours of effort for a very small percentage of users.

Just detect the browser and place a bar notifying the IE users that their browser is not supported.